# Tensorflow 2: Sort a 3D tensor accoding to a 2D tensor

Tags: python, sorting, tensorflow

I have  a 3D tensor with batch, sequence, feature dimension (N,s,e). It is a sequence of probability distributions. Then I want to order them according to the integer corresponding to the highest predictions. So say

```
x_probabs = 3D tensor (ex: [[[0.5, 0.1, 0.4], [0.3, 0.3, 0.4], [0.1,
0.8, 0.1]]]; # shape N s e

x = tf.argmax(x_probabs, axis=-1) = [[0, 2, 1]]; # shape N s
```

or another example would be

```
x_probabs=[[[0.6, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.6], [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.6,0.1]]];

x = [[0, 4, 3]];
```

If i wanted to order x i can do `ordered_x = tf.sort(x, axis=-1)`, then to get the ordering i can do `indices_sorted_x = tf.argsort(x, axis=-1)`. I want the same ordering applied to x_probabs and i am confused how to that, i have tried `sorted_x_probabs = tf.gather(x_probabs, indices_sorted_x)` but it doesn't work because the indices are for a 2D tensor and not a 3D one. I'm stuck here.

The following is what it would look like for the first example

```
sorted_x = [[0,1,2]];
sorted_x_probabs = [[[0.5, 0.1, 0.4],[0.1,
    0.8, 0.1],[0.3, 0.3, 0.4]]];
```

This would be for the 2nd example

```
sorted_x = [[0,3,4]];
sorted_x_probabs = [[[0.6, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.6,0.1],[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.6]]];
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `batch_dims` argument to start gathering from the lower dimension:

```
x = tf.gather(x_probabs, x, batch_dims=1)
```

Comment: thank you for the answers. I think this only works because x by coincidence is the arrangement needed but if I had probabilities distributions over 5 numbers for example:

`x_probabs=[[[0.6, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.6], [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.6,0.1]]]`

then x

`x = [[0, 4, 3]]`

Comment: sorted = tf.gather(x_probabs, tf.argsort(x, axis=-1), batch_dims=1) works. thank you very much

Comment: sorry newbie haha. Clicked the up a while ago, i overlooked the grey check haha.